# Getting 429 response on single request

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, spotify

I would like to prevent 429 responses from Spotify API in an elegant way. It's my first time working with asyncio.
The program aims to gather information about all songs from a given artists. I make a list of tasks for each step (getting artists' ids, then the ids of their albums etc.) and then use asyncio.gather to launch the tasks before proceeding to the next step.

```
class MusicData():
    #limit=asyncio.Semaphore(3)
    limit = AsyncLimiter(1,30)
    @classmethod
    async def create(cls, *artists):
        self=MusicData()
        self.req_count=0

        """1. Uzyskanie tokena"""
        self.token=await self.get_token()

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            """2. Uzyskanie ID podanych artystów"""
            artists_list=list(artists)
            url="https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"
            query="?q={}&type=artist&limit=1"
            #zebranie zadań (requesty do uzyskania id rozważanych artystów)
            tasks_artists=self.get_tasks(session, artists_list, url, query)

            #czekamy, az zbierzemy wszystkie odpowiedzi
            artists_responses=await asyncio.gather(*tasks_artists) #lista obiektów typu ClientResponse

            #dla kazdej odpowiedzi wydobywamy id i dodajemy do listy id artystów
            self.artists_ids=[]
            for response in artists_responses:
                json_result = await response.json() #nie możemy działać na obiekcie asynchronicznym bez odczekania await lub asyncio.ensure_future()
                if json_result["artists"]["items"]:
                    self.artists_ids.append(json_result["artists"]["items"][0]['id'])
                else:
                    print(f"No artist with this name exists")
            
            print(self.artists_ids)
            """3. Uzyskanie ID wszystkich albumów i singli podanych artystów"""
            url="https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/"
            query="{}/albums?include_groups=single,album"
            tasks_albums=self.get_tasks(session, self.artists_ids, url, query)
            albums_responses=await asyncio.gather(*tasks_albums)
            self.albums_ids=[]
            for response in albums_responses:
                print(response)
                json_result = await response.json()
                for album in json_result['items']:
                    self.albums_ids.append(album['id'])
        return self


    def get_tasks(self, session, elements, url, query):
        headers = self.get_auth_header()
        tasks=[]
        for element in elements:
            query_url=url+query.format(element)
            self.req_count+=1
            #tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(session.get(query_url, headers=headers)))
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(self.request(session, query_url, headers)))
        return tasks
    
    async def request(self, session, query_url, headers):
        print("making request "+query_url)
        async with self.limit:
            return await session.get(query_url, headers=headers)

async def main():
    start=time.time()
    a=await MusicData.create("carti", "lil uzi", "travis", "yeat") 
    end=time.time()
    print(f"Działanie programu przy {a.req_count} requestach zajęło {end-start:.2f}")


if __name__=="__main__":
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    asyncio.run(main())
```

While looking for possible solutions I found asyncio.Semaphore and AsyncLimiter library. Earlier, I was adding tasks in one line `#tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(session.get(query_url, headers=headers)))`, but due to the fact that AsyncLimiter requires asynchronous context manager, I added a new async function request. Even with one request allowed per 30sec, I keep getting 429 responses from this endpoint: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{}/albums?include_groups=single,album". In a different file, I tried sending only one request to the endpoints where Spotify artist' ID is needed with the same result. Other endpoints send 200 responses. What's weird, two days ago the program was running smoothly without aiolimiter, taking 2sec to send 80 requests (I don't post further code since it's rather repetitive). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so services (twitter and facebook for example) once you hit a 429 will lock your key out for a longer penalty period. Does you header from the 429 contain any link of "don't retry until" attribute